# How can I get DevExpress CodeRush to create NUnit test methods with the tm template instead of microsoft test methods in VS 2010

Tags: nunit, devexpress, coderush

when I try to execute the test or testmethod templates respectively in visual studio 2010 using t and tm respectively it is giving me ...

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;    
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {

    }
```

I want it to give me the nunit decorator instead and stop adding the using reference to the microsoft tooling.

I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely being caused by your test project having a reference to "**Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.dll**"

Remove this reference and replace it with one to "**nUnit.Framework.dll**", and the templates should detect and use that instead.

Comment: Rory,

As usual you were correct.  Of course, I DID have a reference to nunit as well but the MS reference was also referenced and it was earlier in the list.  Who'd a thunk it?  I kept looking for a cr configuration option.  That fixed it.  Thanks again for your help.